# In Angular UI Typehead, is there a way to preserve the match highlighting when using a custom template?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-typeahead

I am using Angular UI Typeahead with a custom template.  When one is not using a custom template, the out of the box directive highlights the matching term.  However, when one uses a custom match template, the match highlighting is not working.

I created a plunk with an example of the issue. [Angular Typeahead Highlighting Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/VzTraud8IsMFm7beePqy?p=info)

Below is my custom template:  MatchTemplate.html

```
<div>
  <span class='type'>{{match.model.type}}</span> 
  <span class='name'>{{match.model.name}}</span>
</div>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `typeaheadHighlight` filter in your template:

```
<div>
  <span class='type' bind-html-unsafe="match.model.type"></span>
  <span class='name' bind-html-unsafe="match.model.name | typeaheadHighlight:query"></span>
</div>
```

You have to use `bind-html-unsafe` as this filter generates HTML (`<strong>` tags around the match).

See [plknr](http://plnkr.co/edit/UjvbAsggUkddtnhQIH7H?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the `typeaheadHighlight` filter (requires bind-html).

A working example would be

```
<div>
  <span class='type' bind-html-unsafe="match.model.type | typeaheadHighlight:query"></span>
  <span class='name'>{{match.model.name}}</span>
</div>
```

See the original match template -> https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/template/typeahead/typeahead-match.html